# Search multiple strings between two specific strings in txt files and display in a datagrid

Tags: c#, string, datagrid, streamreader

I am trying to mine some data from raw .txt files which are saved in a folder. In each file I got **RegretionModel** and multiple **PeakPoints**. 
My Raw data file looks something like this;

> Model ApprunningVersion="10.4." LastExecution time= ......bla bla bla wr3r43f34f **RegretionModel = Linear221**....bal bal...
>
> k7878k7 wef34ferf **PeakPoints = 11.11**.... bal bal
>
> dwedw  wf343f4 **PeakPoints = 322.11**..... bla blaa....
>
> gewwg45gww35w **PeakPoints = 6711.11**.... bla bla blaaa...

I wanted to extract **RegretionModel** and all the **PeakPoints** values into two different **RichTextBoxes**.

```
if(all_files.Count>0)
            {
                var word_1 = "RegretionValue";
                var word_2 = "PeakPoints";
                foreach (string srd in all_files)
                {
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(srd))
                    {
                        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var line = sr.ReadLine();   
                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;
                            if (line.IndexOf(word_1, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                            {
                                int startIndex = line.IndexOf("RegretionValue \=") + "RegretionValue \=".Length;
                                int endIndex = line.IndexOf("\" LAPNum");
                                string flt_1 = line.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
                                richTextBox1.Text += flt_1 + "\r";
                            }

                            if (line.IndexOf(word_2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                            {
                                int count = line.IndexOf(word_2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                                int startIndex_1 = line.IndexOf("PeakPoints \=") + "PeakPoints \=".Length;
                                int flt_2 = line.IndexOf("\" LPPCode");
                                string newString_1 = line.Substring(startIndex_1, flt_2 - startIndex_1);

                                richTextBox2.Text += newString_1 + "\r";
                                counter_1++;
                                label2.Text = counter_1.ToString() + " of " + matches + " completed";
                                label4.Text = count.ToString();

                            }


                        }

                    }


                }

            }
```

It gives me this, as i expected;

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Linear221      |       11.11      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |       322.11     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |       6711.11    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

But the issue is, When I read multiple files Everything gets mixed up.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Linear221      |       11.11      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Linear321      |       322.11     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |       6711.11    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |          1.11    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         21.11    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Which is actually suppose to be;

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Linear221      |       11.11      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Linear221      |       322.11     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Linear221      |       6711.11    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Linear321      |          1.11    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Linear321      |         21.11    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I know, using these two RichTextBoxes are not the best option here. So I thought of putting it to a data grid view without using a database, but I am stuck with linking each **Peakpoint** to a corresponding **RegretionModel**, 
for example if i read one file I have one **RegretionModel** Name and multiple **Peakpoints**, how do i put each **Peakpoint** with corresponding **RegrationModel** to a Datagrid.

I am a newbie, any help would be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you trying to pull data from PeakPoints? So, if something like this: dwedw wf343f4 PeakPoints = 322.11, you only want 322.11?

Comment: Where is "LAPNum" and "LPPCode" in text file